# Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) is for creating services or only configuring/integrating existing services and applications?

Tags: esb, mule-esb

Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) is for creating services or only configuring/integrating existing services and applications ?

I am the beginner and in learning stage. as per my knowledge , If we have different systems like Database , Web Services , applications ...etc we can integrate through ESB , can we create new services from ESB ? instead of configuring existing servcies ?? Could you please explain with the real usage of ESB.

Comment: That question is too broad. How can it be answered short of writing a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

For general understanding, ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) majorly works as a middle-ware for communication between two or more applications. Each application is independent and yet able to have communication with other applications irrespective of difference in format etc. It's similar to Bus-like architecture which is used to integrate heterogeneous systems.
and for specifically your question, it can serve both purposes i.e. creating new services and configuring existing services/applications